# Android Development: Able to Request a SinglePermission, but RequestMultiplePermissions shows no UI

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

Right now I am trying to ask the user for permission to track his/her fine location, following the docs. I was playing around with the code, and it seems that I'm able to request a single permission from the user no problem, but when trying to request multiple permissions (Fine, Course, Background location) the permission UI doesn't even show. What the heck gives? The code is nearly the same.

The code for multiple permissions is here

```
    private fun requestPermissions() {
    val requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ) { granted ->
            Timber.tag("ASDASD").e(granted.toString())
            // We can check if either the FINE or APPROX permission location has been
            // granted.
        }

    if (TrackingUtility.hasLocationPermissions(requireContext())) {
        return
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )
        )
    } else {
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            )
        )
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqNzS.jpg - Single permission request works

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l6bp.jpg - Multiple permission doesn't show anything

I tried following the documentation to a T, but it seems that nothing wants to work unless I use a SingleRequestPermission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Even if several features in your app require location access, it's likely that only some of them require background location access. Therefore, it's recommended that your app performs incremental requests for location permissions, asking for foreground location access and then background location access. By performing incremental requests, you give users more control and transparency because they can better understand which features in your app need background location access.

And then then afterwards it highlights:

> Caution: If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, the system enforces this best practice. If you request a foreground location permission and the background location permission at the same time, the system ignores the request and doesn't grant your app either permission.

So for For Android 11 and up, if you request background location together with fine or coarse location the system will ignore the request. You need to request for background location separately (After being granted the fine or coarse location access)